# How to find php files containing class and code outside it that would be executed during require/include?

Tags: php, linux

Is there a way to detect or find files containing class and code outside it that would be executed while autoloaded or required? Like examples or so:

```
<?php
class SomeClass
{
  private $variable;
  public function __construct($variable) {
    $this->variable = $variable;
  }
}

// example usage
$foo = new SomeClass('test');
var_dump($foo);

// some other code
```

I need to find them in one older project and there are too many files to check them manually.

Thanks.

EDIT: I cannot autoload all of them (as I dont know in what files the unwanted code might be) and even that wouldnt necessary show me any executed code unless it would have some error in it.

Comment: Does your editor not provide a directory search feature?

Comment: If you have an outoload, that script should point you to a folder or folder structure and file naming convention

Comment: If you have a require, that should point you to a specific file

Comment: @RiggsFolly it surely does but how can I use it to find code outside class with class in it?

Comment: WHat do you mean by _code outside class with class in it_

Comment: @RiggsFolly see example. You have file with class (to be autoloaded) and extra code before or after it that would be executed upon autoload/require.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you search for the word class and pipe the result on the word new ?

```
grep -r --include "*.php" 'class' | grep 'new'
```

Comment: Interesting approach but won't provide much help as there can be many "new" usage in class and/or none outside (could be just dumps or some other code).

Answer (score 0):

The *proper* (and least error-prone *but hard*) way to do this would be using PHP's [Tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/tokenizer.examples.php). You could use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get all the PHP files. Then go over them one by one using the tokenizer marking them as a class file when they contain the `T_CLASS` (or `T_NAMESPACE`) token, then skipping over the class itself and looking for anything but those tokens (and namespaces, comments and such) outputting you the filename when you find it.

The *not so proper* method (and surely one prone to false positives) would be writing your own simple parser (which is probably harder than using the Tokenizer) or using some simple regular expression with awk combination to find out stuff that is around classes and namespaces. I'm not too experienced with that though (and I'm pretty sure regexp alone isn't enough) so I can't really provide an example.